# What exactly is jenkins default user "Jenkins" and why is it always used even when logged in with sudo user

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

I've started learning Jenkins with CI along with docker containers.

I've googled to get exact info and also referred to Jenkins definite guide book but didn't find clear answers to below

1. What exactly is default "Jenkins" user ? when is it created ?
2. Even when I log-in to Jenkins with sudo user ( Jenkins installed on Linux VM and have set up security with Linux users ) , when I run shell command it runs under "Jenkins" user and not by sudo user.

Please clarify

Thanks & Regards,
Vikram

Comment: Do you mean [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/127139) sort of user?

Comment: Hi xvan , per link which tells about ubuntu user. But I am confused with  jenkins installation user; as I read Jenkins also creates a default user by name "Jenkins"